# Grid Mouse Click Event

Tags: wpf, events, triggers, grid

i have a problem when i add event trigger to a grid. I want when right mouse is clicked anywhere on a grid a menu to pop up, the problem is when i click somewhere in the grid where there is a stack panel for example the menu doesn't pop up. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `PreviewMouseDown` (or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` or `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown`) event.

Comment: @Clemens Click is supposed to be a combination of MouseDown and MouseUp, no?